# how to rewrite the page url for seo?

Tags: search-engine

How do I rewrite the page url for seo? Is `example.com/3` better than `example.com/?page=3` ?

I want the search engine to record more pages of my products list page, so which url is better? Is it good to include the product name in the url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put this text in `.htaccess`:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /?page=$1'
```